# access google smart lock password from IoS

Tags: android, ios, authentication, passwords, google-smartlockpasswords

I have two questions from this docs https://developers.google.com/identity/smartlock-passwords/android
I don't know if they imply things that are obvious that I cannot see.

1. When using google smart lock for passwords, if the android device is logged in into a google account, from the code of an app you are developing, you can make a request to retrieve a password that is associated to both the google account and that specific app? (if it was previously saved on the same app and an account on another android device)
2. I need to access one of those passwords from an iOS device programmatically. Is that impossible? I saw there was an app called google smart lock on iOS, but it seems to be for two factor authentication. I think there should be a way to log in the user into Google on iOS and then get the password.

If question 2. is not possible, is there an alternative that allows me to store a password that I can access when a user is authenticated using a Google account? Note that is not the same password as the google account.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What does smartlock have to do with ios? Does not make sense to combine the two.

Comment: There is a requirement that if someone loses her android phone, and buys an iphone, it must be possible to recover the password saved on the old phone...

Comment: Can't the user retrieve them e.g. from https://passwords.google.com manually!? Google most likely does not allow this kind of access from 3rd parties, aka you / any developer.

Comment: That is possible if you have not set  a passphrase to protect the password. If you have, you would need to install chrome to see it  as they say here https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6208650?hl=en 
"Note: If you use a sync passphrase, you won’t be able to see your passwords through this page, but you can see your passwords in Chrome’s settings." Also, ideally, the user should not have to do anything but login on google...